# How to properly make event handling with data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, event-handling, android-databinding

as stated above im trying to make a working event handling for several buttons using data binding(method references to be exact), but can't quite seem to make it work. It looks like the onCLick listener cannot find the referenced method. Not sure why is it happening. Here are relevant pieces of code and the error i keep getting:

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), EntryScreenFragment.FragInterface, ImageChoiceFragment.FragInterface,
        AccelerometerDisplayFragment.FragInterface, JSONPostChooserFragment.FragInterface {
    companion object {
        const val MY_REQUEST_CODE_1 = 24215
        const val MY_REQUEST_CODE_2 = 31345
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

    val fragment = EntryScreenFragment()
    fragment.listener = this

    addNewFragment(fragment)

    supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}

override fun screenshotAccelerometer(): Boolean {
    if (isExternalStorageWritable()) checkAndAskForPermissionToWrite()
    return true
}

override fun imageChoiceButtonclick1(input: String) {
    val fragment = ImageDisplayFragment.newInstanceWithText(getString(R.string.url_1), input)
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun imageChoiceButtonclick2(input: String) {
    val fragment = ImageDisplayFragment.newInstanceWithText(getString(R.string.url_2), input)
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun imageChoiceButtonclick3(input: String) {
    val fragment = ImageDisplayFragment.newInstanceWithText(getString(R.string.url_3), input)
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickImages() {
    val fragment = ImageChoiceFragment()
    fragment.listener = this
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickAccelerometer() {
    val fragment = AccelerometerDisplayFragment()
    fragment.listener = this
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickJSON() {
    //   val fragment=JSONLoaderFragment()
    val fragment = JSONPostChooserFragment()
    fragment.listener = this
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickNoXML() {
    val fragment = NoXMLFragment()
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickCheckForInternet() {
    return checkAndAskForPemissionToAccessNetworkState()
}

override fun entryScreenButtonClickImageBind() {
    val fragment =ImageBindFragment()
    addNewFragment(fragment)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.test_menu, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    when (item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            val mgr = supportFragmentManager
            if (!mgr.popBackStackImmediate())
                finish()

        }
        R.id.action_settings -> {

        }
        else -> {

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun createChosenPostFragment(data: PostEntity) {
    val fragment = ChosenJSONPostFragment.newInstance(data)
    addNewFragment(fragment)

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
}

fun addNewFragment(f: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.anim_entry_1, R.anim.anim_exit_1, R.anim.anim_entry_1, R.anim.anim_exit_1)
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f).addToBackStack(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) //potential error
    transaction.commit()
}

private fun checkAndAskForPermissionToWrite() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), MY_REQUEST_CODE_1)
    } else {
        if (isExternalStorageWritable())
            return

    }
}

private fun checkAndAskForPemissionToAccessNetworkState() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE), MY_REQUEST_CODE_2)
    } else {
        //what to do with permission
        openWifi()
    }
    return
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {
        MY_REQUEST_CODE_1 -> {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                //what to do with permission
                if (isExternalStorageWritable())
                    return
            }
        }

        MY_REQUEST_CODE_2 -> {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                openWifi()
            }
        }
        else -> {
            //...
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}

fun openWifi() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable())
    else {
        val bar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.EntryScreenCoordinatorLayout), getString(R.string.internet_check_snackbar_text), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        bar.show()
        bar.setAction(getString(R.string.internet_check_snackbar_action)) { startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)) }
    }
}

private fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
    val cm = this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = cm.activeNetworkInfo
    return activeNetwork?.isConnectedOrConnecting == true
}

fun isExternalStorageWritable(): Boolean {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState() == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED
}
```

}
Fragment :

```
class EntryScreenFragment : Fragment() {
    interface FragInterface {
        fun entryScreenButtonClickImages()
        fun entryScreenButtonClickAccelerometer()
        fun entryScreenButtonClickJSON()
        fun entryScreenButtonClickNoXML()
        fun entryScreenButtonClickCheckForInternet()
        fun entryScreenButtonClickImageBind()
    }

var listener: FragInterface? = null
lateinit var binding: FragmentEntryScreenBinding
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding=DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_entry_screen,container,false)
    binding.handlers= EntryScreenEventHandlers()
    binding.handlers.listener=listener
    binding.root.isClickable=true
    return binding.root


}
```

}
Fragment's XML:

```
<layout>

<data>

    <variable
        name="handlers"
        type="com.example.robert.testapp.EntryScreenEventHandlers" />
</data>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/EntryScreenCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EntryScreenButtonToImages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickImages}"
        android:text="Make Fragment"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.robert.testapp.ButtonSnackbarBehaviour" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EntryScreenAccelerometerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickAccelerometer}"
        android:text="Accelerometer screen"
        app:layout_behavior="com.example.robert.testapp.ButtonSnackbarBehaviour" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EntryScreenButtonToJSONLoader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickJSON}"
            android:text="@string/entry_screen_load_json_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/EntryScreenButtonToNoXmlFragment"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EntryScreenButtonToNoXmlFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickNoXML"
            android:text="@string/entry_screen_to_no_xml_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/EntryScreenButtonToJSONLoader"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EntryScreenButtonInternetCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickCheckForInternet"
            android:text="@string/entry_screen_internet_check_button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/EntryScreenButtonImageBind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{handlers::entryScreenButtonClickImageBind"
            android:text="@string/entry_screen_image_bind_button"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Event Handling class:

```
class EntryScreenEventHandlers {
    var listener : EntryScreenFragment.FragInterface? = null
    fun entryScreenButtonClickImages(){listener?.entryScreenButtonClickImageBind()}
    fun entryScreenButtonClickAccelerometer(){listener?.entryScreenButtonClickAccelerometer()}
    fun entryScreenButtonClickJSON(){listener?.entryScreenButtonClickJSON()}
    fun entryScreenButtonClickNoXML(){listener?.entryScreenButtonClickNoXML()}
    fun entryScreenButtonClickCheckForInternet(){listener?.entryScreenButtonClickCheckForInternet()}
    fun entryScreenButtonClickImageBind() {listener?.entryScreenButtonClickImageBind()}

}
```

and finally, the error msg:

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match signature of any method handlers::entryScreenButtonClickImages
file:C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\AP_projects\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_entry_screen.xml
loc:22:31 - 22:68
****\ data binding error ****

at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:112)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.doProcess(ProcessDataBinding.java:101)
at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:65)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:133)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$200(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.runContributingProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1033)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1198)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1068)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:89)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:46)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:226)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:181)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:93)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:84)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:374)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:64)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:101)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:108)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:395)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:909)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:97)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:939)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:908)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:394)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @Flimzy according to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648, which is suggested by SO when you're writing a title, tags in the beggining are a "Good example"

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/165502), you should not put tags in the title. Your reference says it's okay to duplicate a tag in the title--that is okay, if it's part of the natural language of the title. But "TAG: foo question" is decidedly bad form. I've now also updated your linked reference to now point to the other one, for additional details on tags and titles.

Comment: You seem to have a valid point. Will be careful about tags in the future.